# Can't get pretty permalinks to work without index.php

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite, apache

I've worked with WordPress for a while now and this is the first time I've had this problem, I can't get my permalinks to work without `index.php` on the URL even though `mod_rewrite` is enabled, a few things that might help figure the problem out:

- I'm using apache2 and mod_rewrite is enabled, I doubled checked by displaying the `phpinfo()`
- The `.htaccess` file gets written just fine when I update the permalink options and the contents are default WP Redirect rules but just in case here it is:

  ```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

  # END WordPress
  ```
- The permalink common settings on the option page don't actually show the `/index.php/` part (sometimes when I've used IIS they show it there), if I use any of the common url structures I get a 404 page (not the `404.php` one on my theme but the browsers 404 one) but if I add `/index.php/%postname%/` for example it works just fine.

Does anyone know what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sigh* had to add this to the httpd.conf file on the webserver:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

First time I have to add it manually, oh well it works fine now :)